# Get data from form field to button value in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a form field and a button in a form. The button should get the data from the form field and pass the value as parameter. Please tell me how can I get the data from the form field and pass the value.

form field -

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'productname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

button

```
<?= Html::a('Search', ['/stock/sellitem/printproductledger3', 'productname' => '8904187001305'], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ; ?>
```

The above example work fine because the value is already given here `'productname' => '8904187001305'`
What I need to do is get the value `'8904187001305'` from the form field. Please help.

actionIndex

```
public function actionIndex2()
    {
        $searchModel = new SellitemsbdtSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('_formbtdt', [ 
            'model' => $searchModel,
        ]);
    }
```

This index leads to _formdtbt

```
'action' => ['/stock/sellitem/printproductledger3',],

<?= $form->field($model, 'productname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,]) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

Controller action printproductledger3

```
public function actionPrintproductledger3() {

        $searchModel1  = new SellitemsbdtSearch();
        $dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search(Yii::$app->request->get());
        $searchModel2  = new PuritemsbdtSearch();
        $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->get());
 return $this->render('_printproductledgerbtdt', [
            'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
            'searchModel1'  => $searchModel1,
            'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,          
            'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
        ]);
    }
```

Well, I think I've pointed to wrong issue. The issue is model `sellitemsbdtSearch` is getting filtered but `puritemsbdtSearch` is not getting filtered.

Search Model sellitemsbdtSearch

```
public function search($params)
    {
        //$query = Sellitem::find();
        $query = Sellitem::find()
                ->joinWith(['siSs'])
                ->select(['sellsum.ss_date as date','si_iupc','si_idesc', 'concat("By sales to Tax Invoice ", sellsum.ss_invno) as particular', 'si_qty as sellqty','(si_qty * si_rate) as value'])
                ->orDerBy([
                        'sellsum.ss_date'=>SORT_DESC,
                    ]);
        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => ['pageSize' => 10000000000,],
        ]);

        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        if($this->productname){
            $query->andFilterWhere(['si_iupc'=> $this->productname]);    
            return $dataProvider;
        }
}
```

Search Model puritemsbdtSearch

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Puritem::find()
                ->joinWith(['psi'])
                ->select(['pursum.ps_date as date','pi_upc','pi_desc', 'concat("By purchase to Tax Invoice ", pursum.ps_invno) as particular', 'pi_qty as buyqty','(pi_qty * pi_rate) as value'])
                ->orDerBy([
                        'pursum.ps_date'=>SORT_DESC,
                    ]);

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => ['pageSize' => 10000000000,],
        ]);

        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        if($this->productname){
            $query->andFilterWhere(['pi_upc'=> $this->productname]);    
            return $dataProvider;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You  could  use this way for sending the value of the model to your action

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
      'action' => ['your_action'],
      'method' => 'your_method ',   /// get or post
  ]); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'productname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

  <div class="form-group">
      <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
      <?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
  </div>

  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

once submit you cant get the value in the normale yii2 way

you can see this for more  .. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html

for the second Model  that don't have the same realetd  model and filed as the first  you should use

```
// in $get try retrive the content of $get (in this case i related  your yourModel1)
$get = Yii::$app->request->get(['yourModel1'])
// and the use the value for searching in your model2 with the proper value  
// obviously you should adatp the name in this sample  with  the proper ones
$searchModel2  = new PuritemsbdtSearch();
    $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(['YourModelSearch2Name'=>['yourAttributeYouNeed'=>$get['productname']]]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answering. But it's not solving the problem. I've tried  - 'action' => ['/stock/sellitem/printproductledger3', 'productname' => $model->productname,] but the value is not passing as 'param' => 'value'. I'm getting error - Missing required parameters: productname from controller action.

Comment: In the way  posted  in my answer  the value is passed as  post or get so you can obatin the value using  $post =  Yii::$app->request->post() and the in $post['your_field_name'] but if you need  a param for seacrh try take a  look at  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#filtering-data   separated filter form ...

Comment: This link is helpful. I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: I've applied as per the document. The only issue I'm facing that I need to search 2 models from one search field. But between them any one is getting searched not both of them together. Please let me know how to search them together. I've added the index and controller action in the question.

Comment: For search together .. you should build a proper search function  ... eg:searchBoth() .. in one of searcModel .. and for this using a proper query that return tha data you need  (could be an union between the two models) .. but this is another question .. you can take a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/ and  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html  join or union section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135348/discussion-between-tanmay-and-scaisedge).

Comment: Thanks. By saying "search together" I mean to say that 2 query should run separately at the same time. One on SellitemsbdtSearch, and another on PuritemsbdtSearch and display the result on a singe view page. Let me know when you have time. np. Thanks once again.

Comment: the puritemsbdtSearch   is not filter because  the Yii::$app->request->get()  don't return a proper  value for this searchModel .. probabily the model related or the fileld name are not the same so are unuseful for filter this model ..

Comment: I have update the answer  with  a suggestion ...hope is clear